# Can't boot up Ubuntu - stuck in emergency mode

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, reboot

I have a Dell workstation with a 250 GB ssd with Ubuntu on it and an additional 8TB hdd for storage. I recently installed another 4TB ssd (again, for storage) and am unable to boot up Ubuntu now. It will try but then simply redirect me to emergency mode (or sometimes to the Grub menu). I've tried booting up to a couple of different previous Ubuntu versions listed in the Grub menu or to the recovery mode but without success. The Ubuntu installation is on the path /dev/nvmeOn1. The new ssd is under /dev/sdb1 and the hdd is under /dev/sda1.

Some posts recommended editing /etc/fstab based on the output of blkid but I am unsure what to edit there. Any advice would be very much appreciated!

[I'm posting a screenshot of the contents of /etc/fstab and blkid. Sorry for not posting it as text. sendmail or any other similar command does not work in emergency mode.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkvmK.jpg)

Comment: This command: `lsblk -e 7 -o UUID,NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL,MODEL` will reveal the `UUID`s of partitions too (unique identifiers). It's important. Compare (and correct if necessary) the UUIDs shown by this command and the ones in `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: I would say before you edit `/etc/fstab`, make a safety copy of it, so you always know where you have started from! Even if it doesn't work right now, it's still the closest to what will end up letting you recover.

Comment: @Levente Indeed, that command was very helpful and showed the partition locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite often you are trying to mount a partition that does not exist. Review journal -xb in emergency mode until you see an error message. This will be at the end of the file. If it actually trying to mount a non-existent partition, edit the /etc/fstab to eliminate the mount.

Comment: Your intuition was correct. Somewhat mysteriously the partition locations had changed and the system was indeed trying to mount a non-existent partition. Once I identified the correct partition locations and edited /etc/fstab, the reboot was successful. Awesome!

Comment: so you put a # before  sda1 sdb1 in fstab & boot was ok - so now use lsblk to find the new uuid atc and edit fstab to correct values.